# Table view recycling in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a table that returns a lot of records.
What I have to do is implement table view recycling, so that at first only 30 records are displayed, and then on scroll new rows aren't generated, but the same ones are used to be replaced with new records.

How can this be implemented in angular ?
I  have a simple table tag with rows and columns where I use *ngFor to display data.

```
          <table class="table table-striped table-header table-condensed ">
        <thead class="table-bordered ">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Type</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let row of allData">
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.day}}</td>
            <td>{{row.type}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```